# Plural or singular: "The socks in these pictures [are/is] the left one, before and after it was cleaned." Is the correct conjugation "are" or "is"?

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, subjects, conjugation

"The socks in question [are or is] the left one, before and after it was cleaned."
Is the correct conjugation "are" or "is"?

In the above sentence (and this one), a pair of socks is expected, but it is introduced that the two socks are/is in fact the same one. Should the plural or singular form of the verb be used?

Comment: In English, a verb always agrees with that verb's subject.

Comment: Does anyone have an example of a reference sentence like this where the subject is plural? (The ones I'm finding, including the alleged similar question have a singular subject.)

Comment: *Those cattle are buffalo. Those buffalo are cattle. These eggs are my breakfast today.  Yesterday my breakfast was a few eggs.*  A tensed verb always agrees with its subject.

Comment: Your example context simply doesn't work anyway, because there's only ***one*** sock. So it has to be *The **sock** in question **is the** left one, before and after **it** was cleaned*.

Comment: Diagram it. The socks are. I'd just say sock, singular: The sock is.

Comment: If the entire story is about socks, and the form "socks" is used throughout the story, and the punchline is that it's been the same sock all along, then it's not clear whether the punchline should start with "socks" or "sock". That's how the question arose.